# Activityview Controller does not dismiss on completion

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an `tableView` controller in which data is coming from server. In the viewdidload the request send to the server and activity view controller appears when data come from server then on completion the `activityView` controller does not dismiss even the data set to the `tableView` cells but activity view controller does not dismiss.

**Code I have tried:**

```
 private var activitiy = ActivityViewController(message: "Please wait.....")
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
               present(activitiy, animated: true, completion: nil)
        loadAds(completion: {(status) in
            if status{
                self.activitiy.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else{
                self.activitiy.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }
```

This is the method in which data comes from server,

```
private func loadAds(completion:@escaping (Bool)->()){
        var status:Bool?
        userName=ConfigManager.getInstance().getUserName()
        var userId=ConfigManager.getInstance().getUserId()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            ApiHandler.userAdsList(userId: userId,completion: {(responsse) in
                var responce=responsse
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if responce.getData() != nil{
                        if responce.isStatus(){
                            self.adsList=responce.getData()
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            status=true
                            completion(status!)

                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        let snackbar = TTGSnackbar(message: "There is some error ", duration: .short)
                        snackbar.show()
                        status=false
                        completion(status!)

                    }
                }
            })
        }

    }
```

I want to dismiss the activity view controller on completion

Comment: Try `self.dismiss` ?

Comment: Check if it is main thread or not in completion block

Comment: everything is working well but activity view controller does not dismiss

Comment: UI updation must be done on main thread try dismissing on main thread, or also try with performselector

Comment: now check please I added my loadAds method

Comment: what is ActivityViewController's superclass, is it UIViewController or UIView?